# Erro com insert no SQL Server: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-insert

Seguinte tenho que fazer uma pesquisa e implementar um consulta no banco usando `Merge` e tenho que fazer isso usando um dos scripts usados em aula.

O problema é que quando eu executo o script da o seguinte erro no `insert` e a tabela acaba ficando vazia.

## Tabela Pedidos

```
CREATE TABLE pedido (nr_pedido numeric(5) NOT NULL,
                                          dt_pedido date, nr_mesa numeric(4));
```

## Insert

```
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 527),
(2, '10/10/2009', 632),
(3, '21/05/2009', 606),
(4, '26/06/2009', 970),
(5, '05/05/2009', 606),
(6, '13/11/2009', 527),
(7, '01/03/2005', 181),
(8, '09/04/2010', 181);
```

Após executar o insert aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 67
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: O formato correto do date é `AAAA-MM-DD`, ou seja, `ano-mês-dia`

Comment: Fiz um [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0281b/1)! Um pouco mais na documentação: [Tipos de dados de data e hora](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: Além do que foi citado, pode alterar em seu usuário que está logando no banco o idioma padrão. Assim ele vai aceitar a inserção de valores nesse formato

Answer (score 2):

O formato correto do date é `AAAA-MM-DD`.

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/217fab/1)

Leia mais em: [Tipos de dados de data e hora](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)

Caso queira selecionar a sua data no formato `dd/mm/aa`, use a função [CONVERT](http://CAST%20e%20CONVERT%20(Transact-SQL)).

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), seuCampo, 103).
```

- `103` Indica que o formato de saída será no formato: `dd/mm/aaaa`
- `3` Caso deseje o ano somente com 2 digitos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## [Fiddle com a função convert.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d0e4c/1)

Comment: opa vlw cara, não entendo uma coisa, no SQL Server que usamos na faculdade é em português e os scripts funcionam normalmente inclusive a data no formato DD/MM/AAAA, porém o meu é em inglês será que é isso que causa o conflito?

Comment: @icaro dá uma olhada na minha edição, o idioma que vc está do seu banco nada tem haver com tipo de dados!

Comment: A vantagem do uso da função CONVERT é que o comando fica independente de linguagem da sessão do SQL Server. Escreve-se um pouco mais mas tem-se um código robusto.

Answer (score 0):

Para que a execução do código fique independente do idioma de instalação do SQL Server, e como no comando com a instrução INSERT as datas estão no formato dd/mm/aaaa, uma opção é acrescentar o seguinte comando antes do INSERT:

```
set dateformat dmy;
```

O código completo fica assim:

```
-- código #1 v2
set dateformat dmy;
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES 
   (1, current_timestamp, 527), 
   (2, '10/10/2009', 632),
   (3, '21/05/2009', 606),
   (4, '26/06/2009', 970),
   (5, '05/05/2009', 606),
   (6, '13/11/2009', 527),
   (7, '01/03/2005', 181),
   (8, '09/04/2010', 181);
```

Outra forma é utilizar

```
set language brazilian;
```

antes do comando com a instrução INSERT.

Também é possível o uso da função CONVERT, conforme mencionado por Marconi em outra resposta.

```
-- código #2
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES 
   (1, current_timestamp, 527), 
   (2, convert(date, '10/10/2009', 103), 632),
   (3, convert(date, '21/05/2009', 103), 606),
   (4, convert(date, '26/06/2009', 103), 970),
   (5, convert(date, '05/05/2009', 103), 606),
   (6, convert(date, '13/11/2009', 103), 527),
   (7, convert(date, '01/03/2005', 103), 181),
   (8, convert(date, '09/04/2010', 103), 181);
```

Referências:

- [DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189491(v=sql.120).aspx)
- [LANGUAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174398(v=sql.120).aspx)